# Get Container list in one azure storage account and create the same in another storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

Team,

Thanks in Advance, I'm an IT pro and also learning PowerShell. I have 2 storage account Storage A and Storage B in different diff region and I want to create identical containers in the secondary storage account.

I've found below command which can get the list of all the containers in the primary storage account and then I can use the foreach loop to create the container on secondary storage. But I want to make sure that in the secondary storage account if it has the container name already then my command should skip that container and move on to create the next storage container.

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageAccountContext | ForEach-object { New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $_.Name -Context $Destinationcontext }
```

Comment: Have you tested its behavior in situations where a container already exists? Makes sense to just call it for each one, regardless whether the destination container exists. And if it returns an error, you can handle that in PowerShell, no? But first... just test to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"VM" is incorrect argument against the "-Property" switch for the values we are getting from pipe(|).
Please use the correct name of the property. I have used "VM" above only as an example. VM is property in Esxi(VC) environment.

Please run the below command  & check the output.

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $Destinationcontext
```

It should give you output something like below:
Property_ID      Property_NAME     Property_3

---

Value 1               Value_A                 Value_1A
Value 2               Value_B                 Value_2A

So, now the correct syntax should be:

```
$Vm_to_be_created|Select-object -Property "Property_ID"| ForEach-object { New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $_.Name -Context $Destinationcontext }
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
$storageAccountContext ="Storage_Account_A"
$Destinationcontext ="Storage_Account_B"

$Vm_in_A =@(Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $storageAccountContext )
$Vm_in_b =@(Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $Destinationcontext)
$Vm_to_be_created =@(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Vm_in_A -DifferenceObject $Vm_in_b )
$Vm_to_be_created|Select-object -Property VM| ForEach-object { New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $_.Name -Context $Destinationcontext }
```

Comment: Getting the below error.

===================================
New-AzureStorageContainer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:96
+ ...  VM| ForEach-object { New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $_.Name -Contex ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
   
===================================
This is for storage account and it does not contain any property with name VM.